# c# update program permission

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I have a problem with my updating process, my program is written in c# and i used innosetup as my program installer, everything is fine except i cant update my files because they are in program files..

I already know that data should be saved in ApplicationData or CommodApplicationData directories and I'm using them for my configuration files, i designed a separate application (update.exe) to download new files to ApplicationData (no problem here) but i want update.exe to be able to move downloaded files to my program files application folder.. (update.exe is in program files installed directory too)

I know that i need administrator privileges to do that and i should ask user for that but the thing is other applications like Firefox have done this already without asking user for administrator privileges! how they do that?!

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: In our applications I do it like Google Chrome (e.g.): Do _not_ install in `ProgramFiles` folder but instead install inside the user's folder (e.g. `ApplicationData`). Works very well for non-admin users, too.

Comment: @Uwe Keim I was thinking about it too, very good point i guess if there are no other solutions this is best one! yet google chrome is installed at program files too.. what am i missing!? :D

Comment: From what I recall, I think Google Chrome tries `ProgramFiles` first and if it (silently) fails, it installs into `ApplicationData`. In our application I do not even bother to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think they do it after having their application signed.
You can also sign your program and do the same way they did.
If the application is signed, later u could run the update program without gaining the
admin privileges from the user :)

- Digital Certificate from microsoft is what you require to skip.

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean with 'signing application' please?

Comment: Means, registering your application with Microsoft. and then, changing uiAccess = true in Manifest file gives the skipping ability. Signing is a bit messy though.

Answer (score 0):

Let you're `update.exe` program Configuration to run as administrator.
You'll want to modify the manifest that gets embedded in the program.Change the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` element to :

```
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:0073chemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
            level="highestAvailable"
            UIAccess="true" />
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
```

and setting `UIAccess` element to `true`.
See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742884.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is if i do that windows will ask for permission again and whole point (auto update without user interaction) will be lost

Answer (score 0):

Did You try add an embedded manifest to ask permission?

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

This will tell to OS that your application need some privileges, like copy in application folder.

You can see how configure in : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer, but the problem is if i do that windows will ask for permission again and whole point (auto update without user interaction) will be lost